# Get text from GridView

Tags: android, gridview, textview

i have some issue getting text from a gridview, and eventually passing them to another activity using putextra in new intent, but every time i try to get text app stops. Here is code

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String cJSON;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    GridView gvColl;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Nome";
    JSONArray worker_lst = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableColl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gvColl = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gvCollab);
        tableColl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }

    protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(cJSON);
            worker_lst = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < worker_lst.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = worker_lst.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();
                persons.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                persons.put(TAG_ID, id);
                tableColl.add(persons);
            }

            gvColl = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvCollab);
            gvColl.setAdapter(new JAdapter(MainActivity.this, tableColl));

            gvColl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// this work properly. I don’t be able to get id and name from grid

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Collaboratore Scelto : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }
             });


            }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your log cat

Comment: Your app stop before load data in grid ? please share your exception which you have faced

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code In Your Activity By Replacing it...

```
gvColl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // this work properly. I don’t be able to get id and name
                    // from grid

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Collaboratore Scelto : " + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String currentName; tableColl.get(position).get(TAG_NAME);
                    String currentId=tableColl.get(position).get(TAG_ID);

                }
            });
```

Now You You can The Two Strings Further...

Comment: Good! It works fine! so,(i think), i can pass currentID and currentName to another activity using putextra in my intent. I hope it's right. However code is right! Thanks

Comment: your welcome... just vote up in you find the answer is working fine... on the left side

Comment: Ah, obviousely for a newbie like me, every new procedure will be a problem!! However, looking for many posts and with suggests from all of you, i have learned really much! Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this by replacing your method -

```
gvColl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// this work properly. I don’t be able to get id and name from grid

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Collaboratore Scelto : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

HashMap<String, String> person=tableColl.get(position);
        String name=person.get(TAG_NAME);
        String id=person.get(TAG_ID);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name : " + name+" ,Id :"+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
gvColl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {

                String dataFromGrid;
                dataFromGrid = ((TextView)(p_view.findViewById(R.id.ulr_textview))).getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("PassData",dataFromGrid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Use below code in your new Activity

```
String m_data;

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        m_data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PassData");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, code posted above from quick learner works correctly. I have just used your code, but i have som problem with (p_view etc... What i haven't understood?

Comment: replace p_view with v . Please accept and up vote if above code works for you

Comment: yep, i already replaced p_view with v, (as parameter of onitemclick, but i don't understand what refer ulr_textview...it's my gvcoll?

Comment: Its your row layout textview of gridview .